# Lisp Flavored Erlang: Can't find include lib include/ltest-macros.lfe

Tags: erlang, lfe

I am trying to run a new project which was created by "rebar3 new lfe-main".  However, I am seeing the following error upon my first run of `rebar lfe run`:

```
/home/<username>/src/<project-name>/_build/default/lib/ltest/src/ltest.lfe:4: can't find include lib include/ltest-macros.lfe
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, it seems like `rebar3 new lfe-main` installs `rebar3_lfe` version 0.4.9, which differed from my global plugin settings of 0.4.10.  Changing my global plugin settings to match the installed version seems to have done the trick.